# Spritenode misplaced in World Scene using Sprite Kit in Xcode-Objective C

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sknode

I am building a platform game in Xcode 6.0 using Sprite Kit. The problem that I have is related to the "monster sprite node" which are created by the following method

```
-(void) generateMonster {
monster = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"monster.png"];
monster.name = @"monster";
monster.size = CGSizeMake(monster.frame.size.width, monster.frame.size.height);
monster.position = CGPointMake(self.currentMonsterX, ground.position.y + monster.frame.size.height);
monster.zPosition = 3.0;
monster.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:monster.size];
monster.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = monsterCategory;

SKAction *moveRight = [SKAction moveByX:30.0 y:0 duration:1.0];
SKAction *moveLeft = [SKAction moveByX:-30.0 y:0 duration:0.5];
SKAction *pulseMovement = [SKAction sequence:@[moveRight, moveLeft]];
[monster runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:pulseMovement]];
[self.world addChild:monster];
self.currentMonsterX += (arc4random() % 400) + 100;
}
```

the position of monster in the debugging is OK "about 50.0", but when it placed to the other SKNode *World which contains all other contents like clouds, stars and hero, the monster.position.y gets a negative value which moves it way below "about -9000"!!?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where are you getting the position of 50 from? When adding to worldNode, does the monster position change instantaneously or is it caused by the SKAction?

Comment: I got the 50 from 
monster.position.y = ground.position.y + monster.frame.size.height;
So it is almost 50 all the time at the time of creation, but after a while it gets crazy with -9000 or less!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad .. 
I had a little logic mistake in the order of creation .. Here is what I was doing, just in case someone else stuck with the same mistake.

The problem was in the code line:

```
monster.position = CGPointMake(self.currentMonsterX, ground.position.y + monster.frame.size.height);
```

Precisely at "ground.position.y" since the node "ground" was not yet created and hence the monsters were falling and thus the -9000 or lower.

Sorry about that.